# Removing Variables using PCA in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

I tried searching for this but could not find the info. I am conducting a linear regression using 10 variables (1 y variable and 9 x variables). All the variables are correlated. I want to see if I need all 9 variables or not. How do I use the data from PCA to eliminate variables? 
I conducted PCA on all 10 variables using `prcomp()` and got the following results:

```
Importance of components:
                          PC1     PC2     PC3     PC4     PC5     PC6     PC7     PC8     PC9     PC10
Standard deviation     0.1021 0.04005 0.03464 0.03114 0.02414 0.02047 0.01708 0.01425 0.01308 0.003287
Proportion of Variance 0.6567 0.10101 0.07555 0.06104 0.03668 0.02639 0.01838 0.01278 0.01078 0.000680
Cumulative Proportion  0.6567 0.75773 0.83328 0.89432 0.93100 0.95738 0.97576 0.98854 0.99932 1.000000

Rotation:
               PC1          PC2         PC3         PC4         PC5         PC6         PC7         PC8          PC9         PC10
 [1,] -0.219033940  0.009323363  0.14371969  0.06987706  0.19302513 -0.02648874  0.16654618 -0.06567080 -0.925393447  0.005948459
 [2,] -0.007661133 -0.027804546 -0.24045564  0.13997803  0.00461297 -0.13195868  0.13625008  0.05140013 -0.005668700 -0.939724900
 [3,] -0.053184446 -0.212036806 -0.26744318  0.36220366 -0.53094911  0.24356319 -0.04692857 -0.62944042 -0.084900337  0.051564259
 [4,] -0.188804651  0.062154139 -0.08807850  0.18886008  0.19969440 -0.59987987 -0.68882923 -0.20548388 -0.004509710  0.024501524
 [5,] -0.299789863  0.080676352 -0.62720621 -0.23335343  0.37274825  0.50767975 -0.23796461  0.03549668 -0.025233090  0.023917725
 [6,] -0.013478134 -0.052386807 -0.58015768  0.34394876 -0.01276741 -0.38994226  0.42009710  0.31887185  0.002157408  0.334375266
 [7,] -0.380565266  0.227200067  0.23992808  0.40306010  0.46135693  0.09059073  0.35930614 -0.34019038  0.342613874  0.015991214
 [8,] -0.432463682  0.037822199  0.20765408  0.45337044 -0.30497494  0.26299209 -0.26947304  0.57196490  0.008807625 -0.029461460
 [9,] -0.654931547  0.158646794 -0.01629962 -0.51083458 -0.39357245 -0.27198634  0.20326283 -0.08572653  0.083798804 -0.010738521
[10,] -0.250287731 -0.928894500  0.10639604 -0.08339656  0.20266163 -0.03955488  0.02948133  0.03827340  0.106117791  0.002154660
```

Comment: Sorry the formatting did not carry over when I copy pasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it sounds like you are facing a model selection problem, you want to choose the best variables without overfitting correct?

PCA may not be the way to go for feature selection, here's one discussion of it:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27300/using-pca-for-feature-selection

The usual purpose of PCA is dimensionality reduction, i.e. describing relationships in your data using fewer dimensions than are actually present. A component that explains a lot of variance could be a good feature but not necessarily, its not exactly geared towards that purpose.

If what you want to do is pare down the number of features in your model, I would suggest using an information criterion like the [AIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion). You can easily use this is R with the `stepAIC` function like so:

```
library(MASS)
fit = lm(Sepal.Length ~ .^2,data=iris)
step <- stepAIC(fit, direction="backward")
step$anova
>> Stepwise Model Path 
>> Analysis of Deviance Table
>> 
>> Initial Model:
>> Sepal.Length ~ (Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width + Species)^2
>> 
>> Final Model:
>> Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width + Species + 
>>   Sepal.Width:Petal.Width + Petal.Length:Species + Petal.Width:Species
```

At each step it trims out another feature, minimizing on AIC. There is a lot more that goes into model selection, and a lot of things to consider and adjust, so this is not a proscriptive guide, just wanted to bring it up as something to consider.

Comment: Very Helpful. So if I understand correctly PCA will not help me eliminate variables it will only help me reduce dimensions by being able to reduce principal components.

Comment: Right, at a high level PCA is a summary of what your data looks like overall, but what you are really interested is how your variables relate to your dependent variable, and PCA is telling you how they all relate to each other. A principal component that explains a lot of variance might not be explaining the variance you are interested in, which is the variance in your dependent variable, it might be explaining some arbitrary variance in these 9 variables that you dont care about at all