# Reduce dimensions using PCA in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, pca

I have a large dataset of 63,000 points and 120 dimensions, after normalising and removing NA columns I used PCA, which informed me that the first 7 PCs account for more than 98% of the variance of the data.

Like this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18921317/removing-variables-using-pca-in-r), I received this data. But I am not sure what to do with it. The post that I linked doesn't really explain and instead proposes an alternative method. How can I use the PCA results to reduce the dimensionality of my dataset exactly? My aim is after I reduce the columns to use the remaining to design a linear model `lm()` in R that explains the dependent variable.

```
    Importance of components:
                          PC1     PC2     PC3     PC4     PC5     PC6     PC7     PC8     PC9     PC10
Standard deviation     0.1021 0.04005 0.03464 0.03114 0.02414 0.02047 0.01708 0.01425 0.01308 0.003287
Proportion of Variance 0.6567 0.10101 0.07555 0.06104 0.03668 0.02639 0.01838 0.01278 0.01078 0.000680
Cumulative Proportion  0.6567 0.75773 0.83328 0.89432 0.93100 0.95738 0.97576 0.98854 0.99932 1.000000

Rotation:
               PC1          PC2         PC3         PC4         PC5         PC6         PC7         PC8          PC9         PC10
 [1,] -0.219033940  0.009323363  0.14371969  0.06987706  0.19302513 -0.02648874  0.16654618 -0.06567080 -0.925393447  0.005948459
 [2,] -0.007661133 -0.027804546 -0.24045564  0.13997803  0.00461297 -0.13195868  0.13625008  0.05140013 -0.005668700 -0.939724900
 [3,] -0.053184446 -0.212036806 -0.26744318  0.36220366 -0.53094911  0.24356319 -0.04692857 -0.62944042 -0.084900337  0.051564259
 [4,] -0.188804651  0.062154139 -0.08807850  0.18886008  0.19969440 -0.59987987 -0.68882923 -0.20548388 -0.004509710  0.024501524
 [5,] -0.299789863  0.080676352 -0.62720621 -0.23335343  0.37274825  0.50767975 -0.23796461  0.03549668 -0.025233090  0.023917725
 [6,] -0.013478134 -0.052386807 -0.58015768  0.34394876 -0.01276741 -0.38994226  0.42009710  0.31887185  0.002157408  0.334375266
 [7,] -0.380565266  0.227200067  0.23992808  0.40306010  0.46135693  0.09059073  0.35930614 -0.34019038  0.342613874  0.015991214
 [8,] -0.432463682  0.037822199  0.20765408  0.45337044 -0.30497494  0.26299209 -0.26947304  0.57196490  0.008807625 -0.029461460
 [9,] -0.654931547  0.158646794 -0.01629962 -0.51083458 -0.39357245 -0.27198634  0.20326283 -0.08572653  0.083798804 -0.010738521
[10,] -0.250287731 -0.928894500  0.10639604 -0.08339656  0.20266163 -0.03955488  0.02948133
```

Comment: If you're trying to do regression anyway, just use [PCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_regression). Or the lasso, which is more comprehensible.

Comment: Thank you very much but what about PCA? How do I proceed from here? I can see the cumulative proportion but how do I use it? Yeah, you decide that you will keep the 7 PC's but then what? What variables do you keep from the data?

Comment: The answer to your question arguably belongs on CrossValidated, but it looks like this: you multiply your data matrix with the transpose of the matrix of the principal components (vectors) that you want to keep, and your result will be a matrix with only that many columns. You're projecting the data into the space of those components. R will give you the rotation matrix as a member of the output struct that is being formatted nicely above in your cited output.

Comment: Thank you @bright-star I will try this out!

Comment: @alistaire I saw that you marked my question as 'an answered already'. I do not know if you actually read my post but I include this answer (click the link) and I say that it doesn't explain how I will actually use the results. Instead proposes another method like you did.

Comment: Well, if someone needs an answer can't really reply bellow the original "so what we do guys?", can we now? We do not need MCVE because we both ask what are the next steps AFTER you perform PCA. It's very general question that providing the results some can give a theoretical or even practical answer. Like very kindly bright-star answered, and he suggested to move the question to a more relevant forum instead. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, thought the original was you because the data was the same. Open-ended questions are not within the purview of SO, though; "Too broad" is one of the close-vote reasons, as is lack of an MCVE, which aside from duplicates is the reason most common reason questions get closed on the R tag.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this to me. I will try to be more specific next time and follow the steps you suggested.

Comment: @Sitherion Perhaps use `broom` package to tidy things up. If `df` is your dataframe, then you could do - `library(broom)`, `pc <- prcomp(data = df, scale = TRUE)` and `au <- augment(pc, data = df)`.  And in your case select only the first 7 PC columns - `.fittedPC1` to `.fittedPC7`